# reflection on surface

Tags: rendering, node-editor, light, lighting, pbr

I want to get some light coming through the window but At the end of the render, just after the first denoised tiles, I notice that there is some undesirable reflection on the floor surface that I don't see on the rendered display as you can see in the pictures.
[image]

in the rendered mode this reflection does not appear

[image]

Somebody help me to solve this please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The camera doesn't appear to be the same used for preview and final renders. There's something strange seen through window, like the nature through the left one and another room - through the right one. The reflection on the floor can be something like hidden object which seems to have emitting material

Comment: Ok Yes some objects are linked but not the camera. That's why they are different. I will reduce the strenght of the enviroment texture and will let you know in about 5 hours because it takes that long to render. Thanks.

Comment: I reduced the strength of the enviroment image from 10 to 1 and it didnt work, but Yes, you were right. It was some extra faces hidden around the window. I just found them and deleted them. Thank you very much.